# Reference request: self-contained rigorous introductions to "cool" topics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation

I am looking for some self-contained (*i.e.*, providing *all necessary background information*) ***rigorous*** introductions to topics perceived as "cool" to propose to (***really***) advanced high school students specializing in math. For example, I am thinking about *Invitation to Dynamical Systems* by Scheinerman. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If they are really advanced, why do you have to make it "cool"? I would have thought the really advanced people didn't need the "maths can be cool" stuff.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I'm not the one making the requirements for the topics in this particular occasion. Besides, everyone needs to be reminded that math is cool sometimes ;).

Comment: @SuzuHirose Also, I mean advanced compared to regular high-schooler. So, you might as well consider 1st or 2nd year of university level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* (Hoffstein, Pipher, Silverman) could fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

The Knot Book, by Colin C Adams is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

*Sets for Mathematics* by Lawvere and Rosebrugh is a serious introduction to category theory,  intended for high school students.

Answer (score 0):

*An Introduction to Abstract Algebra* (Pinter) is rigorous but should be accessible to bright high school students who can handle proofs.